# NSDictionary leak misunderstanding

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, nsdictionary, memory-leaks

Please someone tell me why retaining NSMutabledictionary after some operations is ok, but retain on creation gives a leak.

```
-(void) Func2
{
    NSString *_errorDesc;
    NSPropertyListFormat format;
    NSString *_plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"List" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSData *_plistData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:_plistPath];
    NSDictionary *dataDict = (NSDictionary *) [NSPropertyListSerialization
                                               propertyListFromData:_plistData
                                               mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                                               format:&format
                                               errorDescription:&_errorDesc];



    for (int i = 0; i<[dataDict count]; i++)
    {
        [_ups setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil]forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
    }

    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:_ups forKey:@"Ups"];
    [defaults synchronize];

}

-(void) Func1
{
    _ups = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    //_ups = [[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]retain]; = leak
    //_ups = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]; = leak


    if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Ups"])
    {
        [self Func2];
    }else{
        _ups = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Ups"];
    }
    [_ups retain]; // - ok
}
```

Instruments->Leaks shows that leak detected only when I trying to retain on creation, but if I retain after filling a dictionary all fine.

Thanks.

Comment: If you run analyze the error should be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at just one of the `if` paths (the second) reduces to this:

```
_ups = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
```

// Returns a retained instance assigned to _ups.

```
_ups = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Ups"];
```

// Now a new instance is  assigned to "_ups` without releasing the first instance.

```
[_ups retain];
```

//The above retain is incorrect since the method name does not start with "new" or have "copy" in it. This implies that the returned value should be autoreleased. Review Objective-C naming conventions. See [Apple's Objective-C Conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html).

All in all, best practice is to use ARC. With ARC the first instance would have been automatically released.

Comment: Thank you for saving my mind! Got it. Problem fixed) And thanks for analyzer, helps me to fix some more problems. Sorry can't vote for answer,because of low reputation :(